# How to clear suggestions from login form in django

Tags: django

I'm working on a project in Django and I have a login form. I have added and deleted some users with register new user form. Now when I enter new login it shows me suggestions of the names that I added earlier I want to remove these suggestions. I have no clue what to do.

Comment: These are not suggestions generated by Django, these are suggestions of your browser. You likely can "clear form data" or something similar.

Comment: that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not suggestions generated by Django, these are suggestions of your browser. You likely can "clear form data" or something similar. – Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

You can add `autocomplete="off"` to your form element, so as not to allow any autocompletion in your login form.

If you only want to remove these *specific* suggestions, you should "clear form data" from your browser, as Willem Van Onsem suggested.